# VBA Calculate Number of Days in Weekend

Tags: vba, excel, date

I'm searching for ways to **calculate number of days in weekend (Saturday and Sunday) between two dates** using VBA.

I've searched through webs but all shows how to calculate working days (some use DateDiff, some use Networkdays) but there's no for days in weekend, and I'm already success to do this for working days.

Example :

From date 3/10/2015 to  9/10/2015, it should return 2 days (Saturday and Sunday, not 5 days(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thusday, Friday).

<<< Update 2/11/2015 >>>

I try to change the code according to @R3uK style, but the answers are 'weird' and I don't understand why the result can be like that. Here' the code :

```
Sub DateWeekDiff()
Sheets("Duplicate Removed").Activate
Dim Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date, StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
Dim WeekendDays As Long, CountWeekendDays As Long, i As Long
Dim lrow As Long
Dim PRow As Long
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Set CurrentSheet = Excel.ActiveSheet
FRow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
lrow = CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows(CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row
WeekendDays = 0

For PRow = lrow To 2 Step -1
'If CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AD").Value <> "" And CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "T").Value <> "" Then _
'    CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AP").Value = Abs(DateDiff("d", (CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AD").Value), (CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "T").Value)))

For i = 0 To DateDiff("d", CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AD").Value, CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "T").Value)
    Select Case Weekday(DateAdd("d", i, CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AD").Value))
        Case 1, 7
            WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
    End Select
Next i
    CountWeekendDays = WeekendDays
    CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AL").Value = CountWeekendDays
Next PRow
End Sub
```

The result turns (as example) AD = 26/1/2015  5:00:00 PM and T = 13/1/2015  8:05:00 AM  equal to AL = 807878.
The looping also very slow (Not Responding for a while).

Comment: Total days - NetWorkingDays?

Comment: I know this is answered already, but if you have this for working days, why don't  you just simply do Date difference and subtract working days? (assuming you don't count in holidays)

Comment: Coz actually I want calculate not just date but hours. So if use DateDiff("d", Day1, Day2) will give different answer than Day1 - Day2 . Using Networkdays different answer than Day1 - Day2. Day1 -Day2 will simply give answer exactly like I need (Example : 30/10/2015 3:00pm - 30/10/2015 3.45pm will give 0.45, meanwhile DateDiff will give 1)

Comment: @R3uK can you please review this? Sorry for troubling. Thanks!

Comment: @IlhamideaZ : Take a look at my answer, I tried to detail my explanations and to show you how to use functions! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do the trick :

```
Public Function CountWeekendDays(Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date) As Long 
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, _
        WeekendDays As Long, i As Long 
    If Date1 > Date2 Then
        StartDate = Date2
        EndDate = Date1 
    Else
        StartDate = Date1
        EndDate = Date2 
    End If 
    WeekendDays = 0 
    For i = 0 To DateDiff("d", StartDate, EndDate)
        Select Case Weekday(DateAdd("d", i, StartDate))
            Case 1, 7
                WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
        End Select 
    Next i
    CountWeekendDays = WeekendDays 
End Function
```

AS it is a `Public Function`, after putting it into any module, you can use it directly in Excel like this `=CountWeekendDays(A1,B1)` or in your loop like this :

```
For i = 2 to 50
    variable = CountWeekendDays(Cells(i, "AD"), Cells(i, "T"))
next i
```

And here is your whole sub curated from useless stuff :

```
Sub DateWeekDiff()
    Dim FRow As Long, Lrow As Long, PRow As Long
    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Set CurrentSheet = Excel.Sheets("Duplicate Removed")

    With CurrentSheet
        FRow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For PRow = Lrow To 2 Step -1
            .Cells(PRow, "AL").Value = _
                CountWeekendDays(.Cells(PRow, "AD").Value, .Cells(PRow, "T").Value)
        Next PRow
    End With
End Sub
```

So you just have to paste the function at the start of my post and after you can use it like I did right above, or directly in Excel (this is for the cell AL2) `=CountWeekendDays(AD2,T2)`

Comment: I'd already found the way that nearly similar like yours. But from this way, I can't do looping. Actually the StartDate and EndDate are from two columns in many rows. How can loop this?

Comment: Here is the code that I currently use :


Dim date1 As Date, date2 As Date, dateToCheck As Date
Dim daysBetween As Integer, weekdays As Integer, i As Integer

weekdays = 0
date1 = Range("AD6")
date2 = Range("T6")
daysBetween = DateDiff("d", date1, date2)

For i = 0 To daysBetween

dateToCheck = DateAdd("d", i, date1)

If (Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 2 And Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 3 And Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 4 And Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 5 And Weekday(dateToCheck) <> 6) Then
    weekdays = weekdays + 1
End If

Next i

MsgBox weekdays & " weekdays between these two dates"

But I failed to loop this

Comment: @IlhamideaZ : Don't post long code in comments, edit your answer to include it! ;) And **as it is a function, the whole purpose of those, is that you can use it inside a loop like this** `variable = CountWeekendDays(Date1, Date2)` replacing `Date1` for example by `Cells(i, "D")` ;) So for you it'll be `variable = CountWeekendDays(Cells(i, "AD"), Cells(i, "T"))`

Comment: Sorry @R3uK , I'm new to post here so I don't know how to make the 'grey' sentence XD And sorry too, I can't get ur explaination T.T I'm also need it in Sub

Comment: For the **inline code format**, take a look at this : http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/backquot.htm . The idea is that when you have to **add some details for your question, you edit** http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33430606/edit your post by clicking the `edit` just under the tag of your question.

Comment: No, about the 'I can't get ur explaination' is for ur variable coding, not how to edit. While the inline one really helps. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen my edit in the answer? You can use this in your loop or in a test like `If CountWeekendDays(Cells(i, "AD"), Cells(i, "T")) < 3 Then`. **What else is left to be solved?**

Answer (score 2):

My version of function to count weekend days:

```
Public Function CountWeekendDays(Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date) As Long
    Dim weekDifference As Integer
    Dim weekday1 As Byte
    Dim weekday2 As Byte
    '------------------------------------------------------------------

    weekDifference = VBA.DateDiff("w", Date1, Date2)
    weekday1 = VBA.Weekday(Date1, vbMonday)
    weekday2 = VBA.Weekday(Date2, vbMonday)

    CountWeekendDays2 = VBA.Abs(VBA.DateDiff("w", Date1, Date2) * 2)

    If Date1 < Date2 Then
        CountWeekendDays2 = CountWeekendDays2 + VBA.IIf(weekday1 < 6, 2, 8 - weekday1) + _
                                                VBA.IIf(weekday2 < 6, 0, weekday2 - 5)
        If weekday2 >= weekday1 Then CountWeekendDays2 = CountWeekendDays2 - 2
    Else
        CountWeekendDays2 = CountWeekendDays2 + VBA.IIf(weekday2 < 6, 2, 8 - weekday2) + _
                                                VBA.IIf(weekday1 < 6, 0, weekday1 - 5)
        If weekday1 >= weekday2 Then CountWeekendDays2 = CountWeekendDays2 - 2
    End If

End Function
```

Only arithmetic operations are used in this function, so it is much faster than functions using loops.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite good solution on [Chip Pearson site here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/betternetworkdays.aspx)

You can use it like this:

```
days = NetWorkdays2(StartDate, EndDate As Date, 62) '62 is all days except weekends, (2+4+8+16+32)
```

He also propose a formula which can be directly written in a cell, without VBA.